# why is Django not correctly routing my urls?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to put together a simple website with django. I have my routes defined and they work provided that if i want to go to home i have to localhost/home/home rather than just it being localhost/home. It is the same for my about page. localhost/home/about. If its of any help when i try to go to localhost/home or about django says the page cannot not be found. essentially a 404 error.

This what Django spits out at me;

`Using the URLconf defined in bbsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
about/
home/ home/ [name='home']
home/ about/ [name='about']
The current path, home/, didn’t match any of these.`

bbsite/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
    path('lee/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
    path('dede/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
    path('contactus/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
    path('home/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),

]
```

bulaboysdotcom/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
    path('lee/', views.lee, name="lee"),
    path('dede/', views.dede, name="dede"),
    path('contactus/', views.contact_us, name="call-us"),
    path('', views.home, name="index"),
]
```

bulaboysdotcom/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'bulaboysdotcom/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'bulaboysdotcom/about.html')

def lee(request):
    return render(request, 'bulaboysdotcom/lee.html')

def dede(request):
    return render(request, 'bulaboysdotcom/dede.html')

def contact_us(request):
    return render(request, 'bulaboysdotcom/contactus.html')
```

bulaboysdotcom/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BulaboysdotcomConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "bulaboysdotcom"
```

bbsite/settings.py
(installed apps section)

```
    "bulaboysdotcom.apps.BulaboysdotcomConfig",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information here to troubleshoot.  Please add at minimum, your root, and app **urls.py** files, and your **views.py**.

Comment: I think you might be trying with wrong url in browser try baseurl/about/about it should call the about.html also check if template is configured correctly.

Comment: @Shamim when i route to baseurl/about/about i get the about page, i can also do baseurl/about/home and get home page. My question was why do i have to type baseurl/about/home instead of being able to just baseurl/home. I

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point of how Django urls work.  When you say

```
path('about/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
```

in your root **bbsite/urls.py** what you are telling Django to do is to prepend `about/` to **all** the urls in your project **bulaboysdotcom/urls.py**, and that is why you have to type "baseurl/about/home" instead of "baseurl/home".

The line after that in your root urls.py:

```
path('lee/', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
```

will never be used because Django will find the *first* match, which is `about`.

**Solution**

If you don't want to prepend **all** the urls in your bulaboysdotcom/urls.py with something, then don't include anything in your root urls.py for those urls:

```
# bbsite/urls.py

from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('bulaboysdotcom.urls')),
]
```

That should solve your problem.

Secondly, why not use the `name` defined in **urls.py** to your advantage.

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about')

def lee(request):
    return render(request, 'lee')

def dede(request):
    return render(request, 'dede')

def contact_us(request):
    return render(request, 'call-us')
```